# What do I do if I need to display a certain Preference only for large screens?

Tags: android

What do I do if I need to display a certain `Preference` in my `PreferenceActivity` only for large screens?

Should I have then, say, `xml-sw720` folder or is there another solution?

Comment: As an alternative, I guess, you can check your width before calling `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);` and call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_720);` instead (of course, you prepared such a file in your `/res/xml` folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`PreferenceManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) to load the correct [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You could use an item from one of your [configuration qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) folder xml's as key.

You could also save your preference xml file in the configuration qualifier folder, i.e. `/res/[qualifier]/preferences.xml` and load it with your [`PreferenceFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)